# Is there a VSCode snippet to convert a PHP regular function to an arrow function?

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

Creating this question to answer myself, as I couldn't find it anywhere and I'm hoping it'll help someone else!

When writing PHP (e.g. Laravel) I often have an arrow function that I want to convert back to a regular function for debugging purposes or to add complexity to the return statement or closure process.

For example:

```php
// Convert this:
collect($someArray)->map(fn($item) => $item->value);

// To this:
collect($someArray)->map(function ($item) {
  dd($item);
  return $item->value;
});
```

Once I'm done debugging and figure out the correct code I want to leave in there, I'll often want to put it back the way it was, like:

```php
// Convert this:
collect($someArray)->map(function ($item) {
  // dd($item);
  return $item->correct_value;
});

// To this:
collect($someArray)->map(fn($item) => $item->correct_value);
```

I looked all over but couldn't find an existing VSCode snippet to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a public gist with the snippets [here](https://gist.github.com/madebycaliper/220e92b0ace86eaa5d22e0970bb07183) but for convenience, here they are inline. Just select the function you want to convert use `cmd+shift+p` to open the command palette and select "Snippets: Insert Snippet" and then search for "`converToArrow`" or "`convertFromArrow`".

```
// Place this snippet in php.json to allow it only in PHP files
{
  
  // Other Snippets Here
  
  "Convert PHP function to arrow function": {
    "prefix": "convertToArrow",
    "body": [
      "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/function\\s*\\(([^)]*)\\)\\s*\\{\\s*return\\s+([^;]+);\\s*\\}/fn($1) => $2/}"
    ],
    "description": "Convert a PHP function with parameters to an arrow function"
  },
  
  "Convert arrow function to standard PHP function": {
    "prefix": "convertFromArrow",
    "body": [
        "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/fn\\s*\\(([^)]*)\\)\\s*=>\\s*([^;]+)/function ($1) { return $2; }/}"
    ],
    "description": "Convert an arrow function to a standard PHP function"
  }    
  
}
```

Happy VSCoding + PHPing!